# vert.x: How to send a request to a remote server and get a response?

Tags: httpclient, vert.x

I read the following post about http client with vert.x:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/vert.x/http-client.html

I tried to write the following code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        vertx.deployVerticle(new VertxHttpClientVerticle());

    }
}


public class VertxHttpClientVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        HttpClient httpClient = vertx.createHttpClient();
        httpClient.getAbs("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=John&lastName=Doe",
           new Handler<HttpClientResponse>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(HttpClientResponse httpClientResponse) {

                httpClientResponse.bodyHandler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Buffer buffer) {
                        System.out.println("Response (" + buffer.length() + "): ");
                        System.out.println(buffer.getString(0, buffer.length()));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the code I don't get anything printed in console. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`httpClient.getAbs` returns a `HttpClientRequest` object, which has a `end` method that you need to call to trigger the request.

If you want to do a simple GET request, take a look at the `HttpClient.getNow`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
httpClient.getAbs("http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?firstName=John&lastName=Doe",
    .....
).end()
```

The "end()" makes the request to be sent. In the original post no request was sent.